# why does bash read need a redirect

Tags: bash, heredoc

Forgive me if this is obvious but I can't reason it out.  The intent was to assign a heredoc to a variable in bash.  The correct code on this site is:

```
read -r -d '' VAR <<'EOF'
abc'asdf"
$(dont-execute-this)
foo"bar"''
EOF
```

This works very well.  But I don't see why read wouldn't load the data into `VAR` without a redirect.

-d sets the delimiter as single quote.  Shouldn't bash absorb all the following data until it encounters a `'` and put the lot into `VAR`?

This doesn't happen, of course.  I'm just wondernig why not.

Comment: Why would it treat the *script source file* as the place to read from by default?

Comment: And `-d ''` doesn't make a single quote the delimiter; it makes a NUL character the delimiter (because that's the first character of an empty string; the quotes are syntax, not data).

Comment: ...as an aside, btw -- all-caps variable names are used for variables meaningful to the shell or POSIX-defined utilities; lowercase names are reserved for application use. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html

Comment: Thank you Mr. Duffy.  I knew it would be a rather basic oversight. Your help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

`read` reads from stdin -- not from your script's source file. It would be pretty useless (for prompting the user, reading from a separate file, etc) otherwise. See [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for more on its use.

If you run a script at a terminal, then, `read` by default reads from that terminal; if you pipe content into your script, `read` by default reads from that content; etc.

`read -r -d '' var`, specifically, reads from stdin until a NUL character is seen, or an end-of-file condition takes place (in the latter case, it exits with a nonzero status, but still populates the destination variable).

Using `<<'EOF'` redirects your stdin from a temporary file containing the heredoc's contents. Thus, even though the file contains no NULs, it will eventually hit EOF, and thus control will return.